# Unable to install PHP 7.3 on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, php7

I have a server currently running CentOS 7.6 and PHP 7.1.25. I want to update my PHP version to 7.3 (released on 6 Dec) but I'm having some troubles.

I followed [this guide](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2018/12/10/Install-PHP-7.3-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora) but when I run `yum update`, it throws the following error:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities
4509 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:7.1.25-2.el7.remi will be obsoleted
---> Package php-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64 0:1.0.1-8.el7.remi.7.3 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20180731-64 for package: php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.1-8.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20180731-64 for package: php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.1-8.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.1-8.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: php(api) = 20180731-64
           Installed: php-common-7.1.25-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-15.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-16.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-7.1.25-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
           Available: php56u-common-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php56u-common-5.6.38-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Available: php70u-common-7.0.31-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20151012-64
           Available: php70u-common-7.0.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20151012-64
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.22-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.23-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.24-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.10-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20170718-64
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.11-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20170718-64
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.12-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(api) = 20170718-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.1-8.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20180731-64
           Installed: php-common-7.1.25-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-15.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-16.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-7.1.25-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php56u-common-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php56u-common-5.6.38-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php70u-common-7.0.31-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
           Available: php70u-common-7.0.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.22-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.23-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php71u-common-7.1.24-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.10-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.11-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64
           Available: php72u-common-7.2.12-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So I thought, let's just install `php(api) = 20180731-64` manually, so I googled for that package which led me to [this page](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php73-php-common-7.3.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html) and I tried to install `php73-php-common`, to which I'm getting this error:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi install php73-php-common
Loaded plugins: priorities
4509 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package php73-php-common-7.3.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What am I doing wrong/missing? How do I upgrade PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.3?

Comment: Looks like php73 is already installed: `Package php73-php-common-7.3.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. And from the first link you posted it looks like a problem with some extensions: _The upgrade can fail (by design) when some installed extensions are not yet compatible with  PHP 7.3_.

Comment: Explanation probably here "4509 packages excluded due to repository priority protections"

Comment: In addition to removing priorities I would also suggest removing the conflicting IUS repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is in your output

> Loaded plugins: priorities
>
> 4509 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

So you need to fix priority to ensure remi-php73 repository have higher priority (lower number) than any other repository.

Another way is to remove the priority plugin.

Answer (score -2):

yum-plugin-replace worked for me

::Example ::

rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

yum -y install yum-plugin-replace

yum -y replace phpxxx-common --replace-with=phpyyy-common

Comment: I wish that people who downvote can explain WHY they downvoted...

Comment: Probably because your answer is about webtatic, and question is about php 7.3 which is only available (for now) in "remi"